# How to retrieve computer's ip address from Active directory

Tags: java, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I need to get all computers from Active directory - for that matter I'v composed a java code which uses the following LDAP query: (objectCategory=Computer).
It works fine.
Thing is, I need to extract the ip address as well (currently I'm using projection for the following: "distinguishedName", "operatingSystem", "operatingSystemVersion", "dNSHostName", "objectGUID", "name", "objectSid").

When I'm using the Active Directory Administrative Center - I didn't see the ip address in the Attribute tab - so I thought this data is known to the Active Directory; but then I came across the Get-ADComputer powerShell script - and it seem like it uses something that is called ExpandProperty (ipv4address) - so that means it is there...

My question is:
How can I get the ip address attribute from my java code?

I'm using LdapContext for the searching part.

Hope I gave all info - if anything else is need - please let me know.

Comment: If you add the attribute `IPv4Address` to the list of attributes to return, do you have something?

Comment: The IPv4Address is not saved in Active Directory the Get-ADComputer Cmdlet uses a System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry() to get additional infos about the computer. See https://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/IPv4Address-Attribute-In-Get-ADComputer

Comment: @Olaf Reitz - very interesting article

Comment: @OlafReitz - Thanks for that info! So I'm guessing this is not possible the way I asked it?

Comment: The IPv4 address for a computer is not stored in Active Directory. There is a dnsHostName property, though. You could do a lookup on that, and get the IPv4 address (...as already noted in the previous comment with multiple upvotes).

Comment: @Noam Not with LDAP, you could use the dnsHostName property to do a dns lookup, like Bill_Stewart wrote