# Powershell script not displaying IP addresses in CSV file

Tags: powershell

My goal with this script is to get all machines on the domain into an excel spreadsheet with their IP address in the column next to the name. My script successfully exports the names to the CSV but the IP address field is empty. I have no idea why this is the case as when I print out the output command it shows the name and IP address along with other information about the machine.

Script:

```
$output = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties IPv4Address
$output | Select-Object -Property name,IPV4Address | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\IPAudit
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

THank you,
James.

Comment: Seems strange.. Is it because you don't use switch `-NoTypeInformation` on the Export-Csv cmdlet?, or you double-click the csv after creation to open in Excel where your machine's locale expects some other character as delimiter instead of a comma?

Comment: I have tried it with -NoTypeInformation and still the same result. I have opened it in notepad and all that is displayed is names.

Comment: You're not giving a filename for Export-Csv, just a directorypath `c:\temp\IPAudit`

Comment: Use the `-Append` parameter and see if it works for you? Also, can you try to narrow it down to just: `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties IPv4Address | Seclect Name, IPV4Address |Export-csv C:\test.csv -append -notypeinformation -force`

Comment: See: [How to retrieve computer's ip address from Active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46300052/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

If the very first IP address you query doesn't return an IP address then the field isn't written to the csv, thus ALL subsequent results will not be able to populate the field.

There's lots of ways to code around this but maybe the simplest is to create the csv with fields first:

```
Set-Content "c:\temp\IPAudit.csv" -Value "Name,IPv4Address"
```

Then append your content

Comment: I agree as well.